# How do I configure stand alone Blazor WebAssembly app to allow incoming cross origin redirect?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

Objective is to integrate payment gateway to from Stand alone Blazor WebAssembly application.  My payment page component has a form that submit directly to the payment gateway like this:
`<form action="https://gateway.bank.com" method="POST">`
Clicking submit button in the form redirects correctly.  After the user complete payment transaction on the bank page, user is redirected back to my app along with response header. Although the redirected url is correct, browser throws 404.  Reading more, I found out that since the request is originated from another domain, it gets blocked by CORS.  Read many articles about configuring CORS policy for server, but how do I configure it on the client app to allow incoming requests?

Tried the following:
Added Nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors`
Inserted `[DisableCors]` attribute on the page
Added CORS policy on `Main()`

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
   {
      options.AddPolicy("Open",
          builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader());
   });
```

None of these worked though.

Just to ensure the approach is correct I have implemented solution using razor pages with `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` on page model; it is successful.  Help appreciated to find where am I going wrong with WebAssembly. Kindly note that I don't have a server project, only a stand alone WebAssembly project.

Answer (score 0):

If the request is being blocked by CORS, **there is nothing you can do on your website** to avoid this. CORS is a security mechanism of browsers inspecting the response from a server. If the server does not add the proper CORS header to the response, the browser blocks the response from getting to the site loaded in the browser.

This is an intentional and good (if sometimes frustrating) part of the internet. You would need to contact the bank and request your website be added to the list of allowed origins. They would add your website's URL to the [Allow-Access-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header. Because your URL is now part of the cool-kids list, the browser will allow the response to reach your site and will no longer throw a CORS error.

Comment: Instead of WebAssembly, if I use razor pages web site, I'm able to handle the request by decorating the page model class with [IngnoreAntiforgeryToken] attribute.  Its the same server redirect I receive from bank for both.  How does this work?  Is there any technique to read the request using c#?

Comment: @zir If it works with a different front-end codebase, then I think you need to re-evaluate the determination of it being a CORS problem. CORS limitations are independent of your website - it's between the browser and 3rd-party-server... You say `Reading more, I found out that since the request is originated from another domain, it gets blocked by CORS` Revisit this - are you sure the error is due to CORS and not something else? You mention getting a 404, what specific error message are you getting?